# Azure Function to Receive SOAP Requests

Tags: azure, soap, azure-logic-apps

We have a legacy SOAP webservice that is called by multiple clients.

We'd like to host a copy of the service in Azure PAAS. There should be no changes required from the clients, other than a change to the URL they call.

API Management is not an option at present. I looked into creating a custom logic app connector and got as far as consuming the WSDL but then received an error message stating that one-way operations are not supported.

[image]

What are the alternatives? Are there any example of achieving this using an HTTP Triggered Azure Function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're creating a new implementation for the service contract, the right way to do this is with a .NET Framework WCF service hosted in Azure App Service.

Azure Functions are .NET Core and .NET Core doesn't have an official WCF service implementation, and Azure Functions doesn't help you in any way to create SOAP endpoints.  So it would actually be much *harder* than using an Asp.Net project with first-class WCF tooling in Visual Studio.

[svcutil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) can generate the code to implement the service from the wsdl.